# problems with code in package nomencl

Tags: nomenclature, winedt

Good Afternoon

How can I run this code ?

```
latex <filename>.tex 
makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls 
latex <filename>.tex
```

thanks

Comment: This should not run at all since no true `LaTeX` filename is given.

Comment: Can you explain that better, please ?

Comment: You need to specify which OS and editor you use.

Comment: Angle brackets indicate a meta-syntactic variable. This means you need to substitute `<filename>` with the name of your file. For example, if your file is called `myDoc.tex`, then replace `<filename>` with `myDoc`. Each line represents a command that can be typed in a terminal but many people just click a button on their editor to run the command for them. If you tell us what editor you're using (e.g. TeXworks) we'll be able to tell you what button to click.

Comment: my editor is winedit. Do you know ?

Comment: I don't know anything about WinEdt, but there is a plugin for this purpose, see http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/Nomenclature.php

Comment: @user46548 Also, if you want to make sure a user is notified of your comment, you should write `@<username>`, as I did with with your username here.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. oh I didn't know. Thank you

Comment: Were you able to make it work with that plugin?

Answer (score 7):

I've made a plugin for WinEdt called [Nomenclature](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/Nomenclature.html) which takes care of compiling nomenclatures created with the packages `nomencl` or `nomentbl`.

It automatically recognises the right command to issue by looking at which package has been loaded in the preamble of your document.

To install the plugin, open the file `Install.edt` in WinEdt and press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>.

After that, a command "Make Nomenclature" is available in the "TeX" menu in WinEdt:

[image]

Note that the commands "TeXify" and "PDFTeXify" get modified by the plugin so that using one of them, you get the full compilation process (including the nomenclature).

Comment: Hi! Long time no see!

Comment: @egreg Hi, nice that you've noticed me! Hope you are fine. I'm here just to update some answers of mine regarding WinEdt (updated add-ons and links). Looking forward for your 500k!